# Proving that $(H_0^1)^\perp = H^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis

The question is clear.

Note that $H_0^1 =\{ g \in H^1 : g(0)=0\}$, and $f \in H^1$ if $\sup \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \lvert f(re^{i \theta}) d \theta < \infty$, and $H^\infty$ contains all bounded analytic functions.

What I found that might work for this is the following:

If $Y=H_0^1$, by the definition, $Y^\perp = \{ f \in L^\infty : \langle g, f\rangle =0, \forall g \in H_0^1\}$. Note that $z^n=e^{i n \theta}$ belongs to $H_0^1$  when $n>0$. So integrating against it, it follows that any function in the dual must have all coefficients $a_m=0$, for $m<0$. However, a function in $L^{\infty}$ with that property is analytic so it is in $H^{\infty}$, and if $f \in H^\infty$, with the same reasoning it lies in $Y^\perp$ and hence, $Y^\perp =H^\infty$.

However, it doesn't seem to be clear to myself and I still don't see the part where we conclude the functions are analytic and hence lie in $H_0^1$.

Comment: Just for clarity: Is the scalar product $<\cdot,\cdot>_{L^1}$?

Comment: @Max yes! that's right

Comment: The definition of the spaces should be written more precisely. What is $H^1$? On which set are defined the function considered? The open unit ball? The sup is over all $r<1$?

Answer (score 1):

As @Christophe Leuridan said it, some notations are confusing so I assumed that,
$$
H^1 = \left\{g : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \textrm{ analytic}\ \middle|\ \sup_{r < 1}\int_0^{2\pi} |g(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta\right\},
$$
where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. And the pairing $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ is the natural pairing $\displaystyle \left<g,f\right> = \int_{\mathbb{D}} f(z)g(z) \, dz$ where $g \in L^1$ and $f \in L^\infty$. As $H^1_0 \subset L^1$, the question makes sens. I also assume that the $a_m$ you talk about are the coefficients of the Fourrier series of some $f \in L^\infty \subset L^2$.

However the functions you consider are not defined on the circle $\partial\mathbb{D}$ but on all the disk, thus it is non sens to talk about Fourrier series which makes all the rest of the proof collapses.

If I haven't misinterpret the problem (and I may have, notations are unclear), only one half of the result is true. Indeed, if $f \in H^\infty$ and $g \in H_0^1$, then $f \in L^\infty$ and $fg$ is analytic thus harmonic. It follows the mean value formula that for all $r$,
$$
\int_{r\mathbb{D}} f(z)g(z) \, dz = \pi r^2f(0)g(0) = 0.
$$
When $r \rightarrow 1$, the bounds on $f$ and $g$ imply that the integral converges toward $\left<g,f\right>$ and toward $0$. We deduce that $\left<g,f\right> = 0$ so $H^\infty \subset (H_0^1)^\bot$.

Reciprocally, however, we can find a lot of $f \in (H_0^1)^\bot\backslash H^\infty$. For example, for any $r < 1$, $f = \mathbf{1}_{r\mathbb{D}}$ is not continuous (thus not analytic) and belongs to $H_0^1$ by the same argument as previously (when $g \in H_0^1$, $fg$ is harmonic on $r\mathbb{D}$). Similarly, any function of the form $\displaystyle f = \sum_{i = 1}^m f_i\mathbf{1}_{r_i\mathbb{D}}$ where the $f_i$ are analytic and $0 < r_i \leqslant 1$ belongs to $(H_0^1)^\bot$.

If you want a continuous (and even smooth) counterexample, $f(z) = |z|$ the module function also verifies $f \in (H_0^1)\backslash H^\infty$. Indeed, $f$ has image in $\mathbb{R}$ and it is not constant thus it is not analytic and for all $r < 1$, by the mean value formula (or the Cauchy integral formula) applied to $g$,
$$
\int_{r\mathbb{D}} f(z)g(z) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r |te^{i\theta}|g(te^{i\theta}) \, tdtd\theta = \int_0^r t\int_0^{2\pi} g(te^{i\theta}) \, d\theta dt = 0.
$$
By a simlar argument as previously, $\left<g,f\right> = 0$. We deduce that $f \in (H_0^1)^\bot$. In fact, we can generalize both of the previous counterexample to say that for any bounded function $b : [0,1[ \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f : z \mapsto b(|z|)$ belongs to $(H_0^1)^\bot$.